# "Package.json - no such file or directory" error checking jenkins pipeline on GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, package.json

When I create a Pull Request on GitHub, the job on Jenkins starts to build automatically in order to check.
The problem is that I have the "no such file or directory" error on "Package.json" in "npm install" step in the "Jenkinsfile"

Here is the error

```
    + npm install

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/ephemeral0/_var_lib_jenkins/workspace/s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14/package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/ephemeral0/_var_lib_jenkins/workspace/s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14/package.json'

npm WARN s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14 No description

npm WARN s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14 No repository field.

npm WARN s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14 No README data

npm WARN s_frontend-test-automation_PR-14 No license field.

up to date in 0.235s
```

Here is a part of my Jenkinsfile:

```
env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'nodejs-12.18.3'}"
  env.PATH = "${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  stage('Running E2E Tests') {
    script {
      try {
        sh 'npm install'
        sh 'npm run sauceLabs-test'
      }catch (Exception e) {
        echo currentBuild.result
      }
    }
  }
  stage('Publish Tests Results') {
        junit '**/Results/*.xml'
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `package.json` commited to your repository in the root folder and is the repository pulled correctly by Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually it was working. In one commit just stop to work.
The only way tha we could find a solution was create the next stage on jenkins files who calls an explicit checkout:

```
     stage("Prep for per-dir Jenkinsfile") {
            checkout(scm)
            sh 'git clean -fdx'
          }
```